# Returing data from JNI fuction to Android application code

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I am developing an Android application for which I am using one native C library. This library is used for file decompression.

The definition of the native method is as follows:

```
public static native Long decompress(ByteBuffer src, ByteBuffer dst);
```

**My application code to use this function is as follows:**

```
try {
            File inFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/1"); // source file

            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int)inFile.length());

            ByteBuffer buf_out = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int)inFile.length()*20);

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inFile);

            int b;

            while ((b=is.read())!=-1) {
                buf.put((byte)b);
            }
            Log.d("nims","source buffer zie"+buf.position());
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/2");

            // append or overwrite the file
            boolean append = false;

            FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(file, append).getChannel();

            Long t = decompress(buf,buf_out); // t is some XYZ number

            Log.d("nims","dest buffer zie"+buf_out.position()); // buf_out.position() returns 0
            buf_out.flip();

            // Writes a sequence of bytes to this channel from the given buffer.
            channel.write(buf_out);

            // close the channel
            channel.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

**JNI code**:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL 

    Java_com_company_appName_MainActivity_decompress(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject src, jobject dst) {

        uint8_t* src_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,src);
        const size_t src_size = (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, src);

        uint8_t* dst_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,dst);

        size_t dst_size = (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, dst);
        jlong test = _decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);

        return test;
    }
```

The destination buffer doesn't contain any data.

I have following questions:

1. How can I read the destination bytebuffer back from JNI code to application's code?
2. How can I write the destination bytebuffer data to a file?

I would appreciate any suggestion and thoughts on this topic.

**EDIT 1:**

```
size_t test = lzfse_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);

    ALOG("Size of test %d.",test); // output is 319488
    ALOG("Size of test after casting  %ld.",(jlong)test); // output is -125648933


    //New code from stack overflow
    jclass cls2 = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, dst);
    jmethodID limitId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls2, "limit", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
    (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, limitId,(jlong) test);
    jmethodID positionId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls2, "position", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
    (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, positionId, 0);
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
size_t test = lzfse_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);
     ALOG("Size of test %d.",test); // output is 319488
    ALOG("Size of test after casting  %d.",(jint)test); // output is 319488
    //New code from stack overflow
    jclass cls2 = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, dst);
    jmethodID limitId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls2, "limit", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
    (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, limitId,(jint) test);
    jmethodID positionId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls2, "position", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
    (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, positionId, 0);
```

Comment: To begin with, your native method returns **long** (primitive type), not **Long** (which extends **Object**). I am not sure if this fix will resolve your problem. Also, the good practice is to check return values and faults in your JNI code, *i.e.* make sure that your **GetDirectBufferAddress()** succeeded.

Comment: Thank you the reply. I did check my JNI code and it is working fine. Only problem I am facing is that how can I destination ByteBuffer values?

Comment: Make sure that your code has `#include "lzfse.h"`

Answer (score 4):

When you write to DirectByteBuffer in C, this does not change the size ([**limit**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#limit())) and [**position**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position())
 of the **dst** buffer. You must set these yourself. You can do it in native code:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, dst);
jmethodID limitId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "limit", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, limitId, actual_size);
jmethodID positionId = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "position", "(I)Ljava/nio/Buffer;");
(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, positionId, 0);
```

This assumes that you can retrieve the actual number of bytes written to **dst** buffer from the `_decode_buffer()` function.

And you don't need **flip()**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would try the solution suggested by you and let you know whether that solution is working or not.

Comment: My "_decode_buffer()" function returns value in size_t but I need the actual_size value in jlong. How can I convert between these data types?

Comment: You can safely cast **size_t** to **jlong** for all practical purposes. If there is a chance that your output array will be longer than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, you should reconsider your architectural decisions.

Comment: I  tried that approach but the code is generating exception "Bad limit (capacity 687040): -1264855663"

Comment: How did you do that? What is the value returned from **_decode_buffer()**? Is it really **size_t** ? Maybe, you pass it to **CallObjectMethod()** without cast?

Comment: Actually, **jlong** should be printed with `%lld`, because it is `typedef`d to **int64_t**. But `limit()` doesn't expect **jlong**: it expects **jint**.

Comment: I tried passing jint but the code generates "use of invalid jobject" error.

Comment: How did you pass **jint**? Where do you get *"invalid jobject"*?

Comment: It is still not clear. Which call returns *"use of invalid jobject"*? Have you checked the parameters for this call?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. "(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dst, limitId, actual_size);" returns use of invalid object error.

Comment: I think the possible error is caused by the "dst" parameter

Comment: This same dst worked correctly for GetDirectBufferCapacity? Try to call limit and position from Java after the native method returns instead of calling them from C. Make sure that the native method returns the correct length. Note that the original code declares it to return an Object of class Long, but the actual C code does not create such object. The natural declaration of this decompress method would return **long**.

Comment: Finally FIXED!!! I used the Java code to set the limit and the position parameter. Thank a lot. You deserve the reward!!!